# Uploading files to remote server using WCF

Tags: wcf, tcp

I am new to WCF, I am trying to upload files to remote server using a windows service and WCF. When i run my code i get the below error.

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not connect to net.tcp://74.208.195.53:5000/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0122019. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.208.195.53:5000.**

I tried using the sample project provided in this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFDownloadUploadService.aspx

I read in other blogs that, the port has to be allowed throught the firewall on the server.i did that even tried turning off the firewall on the server but it dint help.

Can someone please guide me how i could get this issue resolved.Any help would be highly appreciated. I am using win7 and the remote server is windows server 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances you need to enable tcp on the server. [this post might help](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/marc/archive/2007/10/23/wcf-hosting-non-http-protocols-in-iis-7-0.aspx)